# Modifying Outlook OFT files via C#

Tags: c#, outlook

My scenario is that I have a huge number of .OFT, Outlook Template files, around 1000.

They all need to be edited and saved with new contact information (updating the To and CC lines).

I have worked with the Outlook C# API in the past but never with .oft files. Is it possible to read the .oft files, modify that needs to be modified and then save back to .oft via the API?

Comment: There are various articles which explain the similarity between .OFT and .MSG files. See a [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957827/is-there-a-difference-between-the-outlook-msg-and-oft-file-formats?rq=1). I figure that you can read the .OFT file like a .MSG file, change the body and save back it to file.

Answer (score 3):

You can

1. Create a new item in Outlook using [Application.CreateItemFromTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865637.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), modify it, then save as an OFT file ([MailItem.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868727.aspx)(..., olTemplate)).
2. Use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) to directly open OFT files using [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetMessageFromMsgFile`, modify them, then save as a new files ([RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`SaveAs(..., olTemplate)`).