# OFT file in Spring response entity mimetype

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, outlook, mime-types, spring-boot-test

I am writing a Spring Rest service which will have to return a file with extension .oft (ex Like Sample.oft)

This oft file will be opened in Microsoft outlook application. But I don't find any specific MimeType to set in ResponseEntity object.

If I need create custom mime type, how do I implement it?

Else is there any other file extension I can use? (.eml extension does not work either)

Comment: Please share what you have tried (some code, or mime-type examples).

Comment: application/binary should work - Windows only looks at the file extension anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Mime-Type for OFT

[Microsoft Outlook Email Template (`.oft`)](https://wiki.fileformat.com/email/oft/) has [basically the same format as `.msg`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957827/is-there-a-difference-between-the-outlook-msg-and-oft-file-formats). It's proven that [Outlook Emails (`.msg`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071425/how-to-get-the-mime-type-of-a-msg-file#31111752) are associated properly by following Mime-Type:

`application/vnd.ms-outlook`

So I would suggest to use this Mime-Type, because will ensure:

- file is *application* specific
- file should be handled by vendor or application (*vnd*) *MS Outlook*

#### File Response using Spring

See Baeldung's tutorial [Download an Image or a File with Spring MVC](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file):

```java
@GetMapping(
  value = "/download-oft",
  produces = "application/vnd.ms-outlook"
)
public @ResponseBody byte[] getFile() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = getClass()
      .getResourceAsStream("/path/to/your/email_template.oft");
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}
```

**Note**: Above implementation uses *Apache's IOUtils*.

See also:
[Downloading a file from spring controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers)

Comment: I am able to download it. But when I try to open it, it says that "the file is already opened or you don't have permission". But the file is not opened and I have permission too.

Comment: @Renga Glad **my answer solved your question** for _mime-type_ and _spring-implememtation_ and **you can download**  For the next _opening-fails_ issue **please post a separate question!** Or research: https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB86515